# construct variable within Object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

Hi I have the following ArrayCollection:

```
priceModel.model.arrayProducts.addItem( {'productID':pc.productID, 'product':pc.product,
'provider1': {'value':0, 'selected':false},                                                             'provider2': {'value':0, 'selected':false},                                                             'provider3': {'value':0, 'selected':false},                                                             'provider4': {'value':0, 'selected':false},                                                             'provider5': {'value':0, 'selected':false},                                                             'provider6': {'value':0, 'selected':false});
```

I have a set Products and the question is that I need to iterate over the Products and access to a certain provider like for example:

```
priceModel.model.arrayProducts[product_index].('provider'+(idx+1)).value;
```

This does not work. How can i focus the code to getting access in each product to it's provider_X?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ArrayCollection you cant use [] syntax - you have to use getItemAt to access the item:

```
priceModel.model.arrayProducts.getItemAt(product_index)
```

To access a property of the object 'dynamically' you conversely do use []:

```
['provider'+(idx+1)].value;
```

So this should work:

```
priceModel.model.arrayProducts.getItemAt(product_index)['provider'+(idx+1)].value;
```